# Centering Verbatim (or not) in Latex

Tags: latex, centering

So I want something like the following

```
If t >= 30

    show = 1

end
```

centered in the middle of the line in my LaTeX project.

I tried to use verbatim and tight center but the best I got was the following:

[image]

It's easy to see that's not correctly centered. This was the code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\\textwidth}
\begin{verbatim}
if $t \>= 30$:
show = 1
end
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

Reproducible example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\title{a}
\author{you}
\date{March 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
some text to seeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{verbatim}
if $t >= 30$:
    show = 1
end

\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a very good solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122197/49683) using environment `BVerbatim` from the package [`fancyvrb`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb), nested inside a `figure` (or other float), instead of a `minipage`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\title{a}
\author{you}
\date{March 2023}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text.

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{BVerbatim}
if $t >= 30$:
    show = 1
end

\end{BVerbatim}
\end{figure}

Other text, other text, other text, other text, other text, other text, other text, other text, other text.
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output]